# Getting not found while using sed command in korn shell

Tags: shell, unix, sed, ksh

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/sed
export PATH
#echo -n "Enter file name : "
read name
if [ -e $name ]
then
var1="$(wc -l < $name)"
print "Total lines in file including header and trailer : $var1"
var2=$(tail -1 $name|cut -c11-20)
print $var2
var3="$((10#${var2}))"
print "Total record count as per Trailer record: $var3"
val=$(($var1-2))
print "total records w/o header and trailer is : $val"
if [[ $val -eq $var3 ]];then
echo " "
echo "Trailer record information for total record count is true"
else
echo "Trailer record count is erroneous"
fi
#echo -n "Please provide journal date string : "
#read journal
#journal=$(tail -n2 $name|head -n1|cut -c42-45)
#print "grep -c \"$journal\" $name"
journal1=$(tail -n2 $name|head -n1|cut -c42-45)
print $journal1
journal=$("/bin/sed '1d;\$d' $name|cut -c42-45|grep -c \"$journal1\"")
print "sed '1d;\$d' $name|cut -c42-45|grep -c \"$journal1\""
print $journal
if [[ $journal -eq $var3 ]];then
echo "All journals are valid"
else
echo "Please check journals manually."
fi
else
echo "File does not exists"
fi
```

when i execut ethe above script i get sed command not found error. Same sed command is running on command prompt. Can someone help me out? I have tried using PATH where sed command is found.

when i execute "whereis" for sed. i get this : *sed: /usr/bin/sed*

Comment: PATH are directories, so you should need `PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin`

Comment: ./validation.sh[28]: sed '1d;$d' sample.dat|cut -c42-45|grep -c "2016":  not found.

Comment: im getting the above error walter! can you suggest where exactly i need to place the {PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin}

Comment: when i give echo $PATH in command prompt i get this:  /usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/home/n3177762/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:.

Answer (score 0):

Try with little steps, like

```
echo "Almost solved this"| sed 's/Almost/We have/'
```

I think the `sed` in this line will be found with your normal PATH.
Look at the strange `sed`line in the script.

```
journal=$("sed '1d;\$d' $name|cut -c42-45|grep -c \"$journal1\"")
```

will try to assign the stdout of the command to the variable journal. And the command is

```
"sed '1d;\$d' $name|cut -c42-45|grep -c \"$journal1\""
```

This is not `sed` with options piped to other commands, but a very long filename `sed '1d;$d' sample.dat|cut -c42-45|grep -c "2016"`.
This is a completely different from

```
sed '1d;\$d' $name|cut -c42-45|grep -c \"$journal1\"
```

or better

```
sed '1d;$d' "$name" |cut -c42-45|grep -c "$journal1"
```

When the header and tail line are small, you can avoid `sed` and `$journal1` with

```
if [ $(cut -c42-45 "$name"| sort -u| wc -l) -eq 1 ]; then
   echo "All records have the same journal"
else
   echo "Something funny..."
fi
```

And please indent your file next time.